# D3 x Axis data is overlaping

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and i'm having some trouble to make a bar chart.

This is the js code:

```
function getPrintKmProduction(w, h, month, year){
    $.getJSON("actioncall", {month: month, year: year}, function(data){ 
        var vis = d3.select('#visualisation_km'),
        WIDTH = w,
        HEIGHT = h,
        MARGINS = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 50
        },

        xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right], 0.1)
        .domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.line;}));

        yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
        .domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.sum_trip;})]);

        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xRange)
            .tickSubdivide(true);

        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yRange)
            .tickSize(5)
            .orient("left")
            .tickSubdivide(true);

        vis.append('svg:g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

        vis.append('svg:g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
            .call(yAxis);

        vis.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return xRange(d.line);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
            return yRange(d.sum_trip);
        })
        .attr('width', xRange.rangeBand())
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            return ((HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) - yRange(d.sum_trip));
        })
        .attr('fill', 'grey')
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .attr('fill', 'blue');
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .attr('fill', 'grey');
        });

        vis.append("text")
        .attr("x", (WIDTH / 2))             
        .attr("y", 0 - (MARGINS.top / 2) +25)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "15px") 
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
        .text("Produção Quilométrica");
    })  
}
```

The Json object is this:

```
{line: 1750, sum_trip: 109}
{line: 1751, sum_trip: 38}
{line: 1760, sum_trip: 165}
{line: 1770, sum_trip: 98}
{line: 1771, sum_trip: 41}
{line: 1900, sum_trip: 131}
{line: 1910, sum_trip: 39}
{line: 1950, sum_trip: 83}
{line: 1980, sum_trip: 5}
{line: 2110, sum_trip: 77}
{line: 2120, sum_trip: 8}
{line: 2130, sum_trip: 150}
{line: 2140, sum_trip: 15}
{line: 2150, sum_trip: 68}
{line: 2160, sum_trip: 4}
{line: 2170, sum_trip: 92}
{line: 2180, sum_trip: 3}
```

The result is this one:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHXI1.jpg)

I tried to change the values on the xRange and XAxis, but no dice. Y part is working ok, i inspected on the console and the values for width and height are been set, but no x.

EDIT:

Console.log

console.log(xRange.domain(), xRange.range()) printed this:

(588) [1000, 1001, 1100, 1110, 1120, 1130, 1140, 1150, 1191, 1200, 1210, 1220, 1231, 1241, 1250, 1260, 1270, 1271, 1280, 1281, 1290, 1300, 1321, 1330, 1390, 1600, 1620, 1630, 1640, 1650, 1660, 1670, 1680, 1690, 1700, 1710, 1720, 1730, 1740,2880…], (588) [265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265…]

Comment: This looks like it should work as expected.  Try 'console.log(x.domain(), x.range())' and see that things look as expected. Working re-creation here: https://bl.ocks.org/jsl6906/f2d6ffeeba886e13950dc656c047619d

Comment: console.log(x.domain(), x.range()) did not work, but console.log(xRange.domain(), xRange.range()) printed this: (588) [1000, 1001, 1100, 1110, 1120, 1130, 1140, 1150, 1191, 1200, 1210, 1220, 1231, 1241, 1250, 1260, 1270, 1271, 1280, 1281, 1290, 1300, 1321, 1330, 1390, 1600, 1620, 1630, 1640, 1650, 1660, 1670, 1680, 1690, 1700, 1710, 1720, 1730, 1740,2880…], (588) [265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265…]

Comment: It looks like you have too many 'bins' in your range (588), because you are using a rounded range band.  Try changing to rangeBands() (instead of rangeRoundBands()) or decrease your number of bands you wish to display

Comment: I see. Tried that but did not fully work. A change a little and made it work merging new code that i wrote and limiting as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out with the help of [josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332731/josh).

I limited my universe and made some changes (shown in the code below):

```
function format1(n) {
return n.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "." + c : c;
 });
}

function getPrintGraph(w, h, month, year, type){
type = "ps";
$.getJSON("/<dir>/<action> (change this)", {month: month, year: year, type: type}, function(data){  
    var vis = d3.select('#visualisation_km'),
    WIDTH = w,
    HEIGHT = h,
    MARGINS = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 60
    }

    if (type == "km") {
        var desc = "Teste";
        var desc_y = "Teste";
        var desc_tip = "Teste";
    }else if (type == "ps") {
        var desc = "Teste1";
        var desc_y = "Teste1";
        var desc_tip = "Teste1";
    }
    xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - 40], .1).domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.line;}));
    yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
    .domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.sum;})]);

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xRange)
        .tickSubdivide(true);

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yRange)
        .tickSize(5)
        .orient("left")
        .tickSubdivide(true);

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<span style='color:red'>"+format1(d.sum)+ " "+desc_tip+"</span>";
  })

    vis.append('svg:g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

    vis.append('svg:g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
        .call(yAxis);

    vis.call(tip);

    vis.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
        return xRange(d.line);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
        return yRange(d.sum);
    })
    .attr('width', xRange.rangeBand())
    .attr('height', function(d) {
        return ((HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) - yRange(d.sum));
    })
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        tip.show(d);
        d3.select(this)
            .attr('fill', 'DarkBlue');
    })
    .on('mouseout',  function(d) {
        tip.hide(d);
        d3.select(this)
            .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
    });

    // legenda grafico
    vis.append("text")
    .attr("x", (WIDTH / 2))             
    .attr("y", 0 - (MARGINS.top / 2) +25)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "15px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
    .text(desc);

    // legenda eixo y
    vis.append("text")
    .attr("x", 15)             
    .attr("y", 0 - (MARGINS.top / 2) +25)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "15px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
    .text(desc_y);

    // legenda eixo x
    vis.append("text")
    .attr("x", 875)             
    .attr("y", 300)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "15px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
    .text("Linhas");
})
```

Thanks Josh :)